# Sacar sólo la información de un idioma con Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo un `Backend` realizado con **Node.JS** y **ExpressJS**, y como base de datos estoy usando **MongoDB** con **Mongoose**. Ésta es la estructura de la colección de categorías:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d712d3b707d601fe0147730"),
    "name" : {
        "es" : "Aspiración",
        "en" : "Aspiration"
    },
    "slug" : {
        "es" : "aspiracion",
        "es" : "aspiration"
    },
    "description" : {
        "es" : "La mayor potencia.",
        "es" : "The greatest power."
    },
}
```

En cada campo se puede guardar un `String` en Inglés y en `String` en Español. Cuando hago un `Category.find()` quiero pasarle el idioma por ejemplo: `"es"` y que solo me devuelva los campos `String` en el idioma seleccionado por ejemplo de esta manera seria el resultado que devolvería:

```
{
    "category": [
        {
            "_id": "5d712d3b707d601fe0147730",
            "name": "Aspiración",
            "slug": "aspiracion",
            "description": "El mas potente."
        }
    ]
}
```

Esta sería mi función para buscar categorías:

```
function getAllCategories(req, res) {
  const lang = "es";

  Category.find().exec((err, categoryStored) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Error del servidor." });
    } else {
      if (!categoryStored) {
        res
          .status(404)
          .send({ message: "No se ha encontrado ningun producto." });
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({ category: categoryStored });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar por que lo he intentado, pero no he conseguido sacarlo.

Comment: esa estructura es muy compleja para el idioma te propongo hacer un registro por idioma `[{
  "_id": 1,
  "language": "es",
  "slug": "aspiracion ",
  "description": "La mayor potencia."
 },{
  "_id": 2,
  "language": "en",
  "slug": "aspiration ",
  "description": "The greatest power."
}]` asi la base de datos te devuelve exactamente lo que quieres y no se te hace complejo realizar otras actividades

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto que puedes hacer la tarea sin necesidad de cambiar la estructura actual de tu Modelo, Esquema o Colección.

Para realizar lo que te propones es más conveniente usar una [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) y no una [consulta](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/index.html)

Como estás usando Express y Mongoose, usaremos la clase [Aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate), y para ejecutar la agregación usaremos el método [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec) de dicha clase.

Primero vamos a definir nuestra etapa de agregación: [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html)

```js
{$project: {
  name: `$name.${lang}`,
  slug: `$slug.${lang}`,
  description: `$description.${lang}`
  }
}
```

Puedes observar que es un documento con un formato específico. En el mismo le estoy indicando que se van a crear 3 campos (`name`, `slug`, `projection`) los cuales contendrán el valor del campo correspondiente según el idioma seleccionado.

Tu código podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```js
function getAllCategories(req, res) {
  const lang = 'es';
  const aggregate = Category.aggregate([
    {$project: {
      name: `$name.${lang}`,
      slug: `$slug.${lang}`,
      description: `$description.${lang}`
      }
    }
  ]);
  aggregate.exec((err, categories) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      return res.status(500).json({err: err.message});
    }
    if(!categories.length) {
      return res.status(400).json({categories: `No categories found.`});
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ category: categories });
  });
});
```

Lo cual produce la salida deseada:

[image: Ejemplo de resultado del proceso de agregación]

**Mejora**

Ahora, si realmente queremos algo un poco más dinámico, vamos permitir que la variable `lang` sea introducida por el usuario en la solicitud http mediante un campo `query` en la `url` de nuestra aplicación.

Para esto vamos a agregar una etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) previa en nuestra agregación, para indicarle a Mongo que filtre los documentos de forma tal que sólo nos devuelva aquellos donde los campos de la forma `<field>.<lang>` existan.

La etapa `$match` sería algo como esto:

```js
{ $match:
  {
    [`name.${lang}`]: {$exists: true},
    [`slug.${lang}`]: {$exists: true},
    [`description.${lang}`]: {$exists: true}
  }
}
```

He colocado una consulta de tal forma que los tres campos (`name.<lang>`, `slug.<lang>` y `description.<lang>`) existan a la vez.

El código completo se vería así:

```js
function getAllCategories(req, res) {
  const lang = req.query.lang ? req.query.lang : 'es'; //verificamos si la url posee un campo lang, sino escribimos uno por defecto
  const aggregate = Category.aggregate([
    {$match:
      {
        [`name.${lang}`]: {$exists: true},
        [`slug.${lang}`]: {$exists: true},
        [`description.${lang}`]: {$exists: true}
      }
    },
    {$project: {
      name: `$name.${lang}`,
      slug: `$slug.${lang}`,
      description: `$description.${lang}`
      }
    }
  ]);
  aggregate.exec((err, categories) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      return res.status(500).json({err: err.message});
    }
    if(!categories.length) {
      return res.status(400).json({categories: `No categories found for language: '${lang}'.`});
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ category: categories });
  });
});
```

El resultado, pasando en la `url` el valor de `lang`: `localhost:3000/path/to/api?lang=en`

[image: Resultado de función mejorada]

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lang = 'es';

const busqueda = { [`name.${idioma}`]: { $exists : true } };

Category.find(busqueda).exec((err, categoryStored) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Error del servidor." });
    } else {
      if (!categoryStored) {
        res
          .status(404)
          .send({ message: "No se ha encontrado ningun producto." });
      } else {
        res.status(200).send({ category: categoryStored });
      }
    }
  });
```

De ahí puedes usar el operador `$or` para los demás campos

La otra opción y me parece más expandible seria cambiar tu estructura de datos

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d712d3b707d601fe0147730"),
    "name" : [
        {"data" : "Aspiración", lang: "es"},
        {"data" : "Aspiration", lang: "en"}
    ],
     ... 

}
```

y de esa forma te queda mas fácil triar querys.

Espero haber ayudado! Saludos!